# Insert textbox value from a form into a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a textbox(in form) and a field(in table) both named **SerialNumber**

This is the control source of the textbox: `=([OrderNr] & (""+[Aantal]) & "" & [SapArtNr])`

I can't seem to make the textbox save the value inside into the table.

**Edit:**

```html
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command82_Click()
    ' Add data to Table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Geleidelijst(SerialNmbr, InvoerOrderNr, InvoerAantal, InvoerVermogen, InvoerHSLSSpn) " & _
            " VALUES(" & Me.SerialNumberLong & ",'" & Me.OrderNr & "','" & _
            Me.Aantal & "','" & Me.Vermogen & "','" & Me.HSLSSpn & "')"
End Sub
```

But then I get error: `3075 Synax error missing operating in query expression.` And if I add date as a format it doesn't work either.

Only when it's numbers, but when there's letters and dots and "/" for example, it won't work.

Any help would be nice, thanks.

Comment: What has this to do with sql?

Comment: You assign the expression to a read-only textbox as its ControlSource. That won't update a table field.

Comment: @Gustav Yeah thanks, I've tried different methods but still no success, updated the post.

Comment: @jens Nothing. was an accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `Aantal` is numeric, so try without quotes:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Geleidelijst " & _
    "(SerialNmbr, InvoerOrderNr, InvoerAantal, InvoerVermogen, InvoerHSLSSpn) " & _
    "VALUES('" & Me.SerialNumberLong & "','" & Me.OrderNr & "'," & Me.Aantal & ",'" & Me.Vermogen & "','" & Me.HSLSSpn & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I could also try this with one textbox (SerialNumberLong), which is the important one. It conaints this value in the textbox: "23423423Q1000NB309 21/0.4 5I" But even with the code you sent I still get the error: "3075 Synax error missing operating in query expression

Comment: That serial no. is text. See edited answer, please.